# Generically instrumenting a React Application

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a tool where I can generically instrument a react app (ie. i want to get notifications every time a component is created or destroyed, every time it is rendered, etc... without having to wrap every component).
Any hints/ libraries/ fiber extension examples I could use??

Comment: React components can get rendered hundreds of times in a single animation frame. You really do not want to try to capture data in an analytics tool showing these events.

Comment: At the very least mounting and unmounting....

Comment: Do you only care about class based components? Functional components don't persist and are never formally “mounted” and “unmounted”, even if you use hooks.